# Proving that if $a$ is an element from a group and $|a|=n$, then $C(a)=C(a^k)$, when $k$ is relatively prime to n.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

$C$ in question title denotes centralizer of an element $a$ in group (say, $G$) and is defined as follows:
$$C(b)=\{x\in G:bx=xb \;\;\forall x\in G\}$$
In order to prove the result in title, I proceeded as follows :

Let $x \in C(a)$, hence

$$\begin{align}
ax=xa &\implies a =xax^{-1}\\
&\implies a^k=xa(x^{-1}x)a(x^{-1}x)\dots,x^{-1}=xa^kx^{-1}\\
&\implies a^kx=xa^k\\
&\implies x \in C(a^k)\\
&\implies C(a) \subseteq C(a^k)
\end{align}$$

For the converse part, let $y\in C(a^k)$ so that $a^ky=ya^k \tag{1}$

Since $n$ and $k$ are relative primes, $\langle a\rangle=\langle a^k\rangle$, hence for every $a$ in $\langle a\rangle$, there is an $r$ such that $a=a^{kr}\implies a^{kr-1}=e$, identity. $n$ divides kr-1, hence there exists some $s$ such that $kr-ns =1$ 
Hence, $ay=a^{kr-ns}y=a^{kr}ey=a^{kr-k}(a^ky)=a^{kr-k}(ya^k)$ [By (1)].

From here I don't know how to show that $ya=a^{kr-k}(ya^k)$. If it is shown, then it can be deduced that $C(a^k)\subseteq C(a)$. And thus the result will be proved.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle`, not `<` and `>`. The former are delimeters, the latter are relational symbols; the spacing is wrong when you use the latter.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks. I was just editing my post but you edited it already.

Comment: The definition of $C(b)$ is not right. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralizer_and_normalizer

Comment: @lhf Thanks a lot for pointing that out. I had erroneously put $b\in G$ instead of $x\in G$. I have edited it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x$ commutes with $y$, then it commutes with $y^n$ for every integer $n$: it commutes with $y^1$; if it commutes with $y^r$, then
$$xy^{r+1} = x(y^ry) = (xy^r)y = (y^rx)y = y^r(xy) = y^r(yx) = y^{r+1}x.$$
Thus, it commutes with every positive power of $y$; it clearly commutes with $y^0$. And if $xy^n = y^nx$, then multiplying by $y^{-n}$ on the left and $y^{-n}$ on the right, we get $y^{-n}x=xy^{-n}$, so $x$ commutes with $y^{-n}$.

Now, you know that $\langle a\rangle = \langle a^k\rangle$. So $a\in \langle a^k\rangle$. Use that to show that if $x$ commutes with $a^k$ then it commutes with $a$.

Comment: How do I show from $a^kx=xa^k$ that $ax=xa$? Since $a\in \langle a^k \rangle, \exists t$ such that $a=(a^k)^t$. Hence, $(a^k)^{t-1}a^kx= (a^k)^{t-1}xa^k\implies ax=a^{1-k}xa^k$. How do I take it from here?

Comment: @Koro: Since $a\in \langle a^k\rangle$, then there exists $r$ such that $a = (a^k)^r$. And what goes in the previous paragraph tells you that anything that commutes with $a^k$ also commutes with *every power* of $a^k$, in particular, with $(a^k)^r$. What is the problem?

Comment: @Koro: Or just commute $x$ with each power of $a^k$, $t$ times. I’m really, really confused about why you are confused.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. I understood it now. I carefully examined the first para. You have used "Principal of mathematical induction" there to establish that if $ax=xa$ then $ x $commutes with every positive integer power of a. Meanwhile, I also noticed that since, $a^k=x^{−1}a^kx=(x^{−1}ax)^k$, we have $a=x^{−1}ax$ since $k$ and $ n$ are prime and $|a|=|x^{-1}ax|$. Hence proved.